# Create Custom Control with reusable properties

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

This is similar to my last post but with a different purpose.

I have built a custom control, but when I set the properties for it... ALL instances of that control on my page grab the exact same property.  I need to be able to set the property to "abc" for one instance of the control on my page, and then set the exact same proprty to "xyz" for a different instance of the control on the same page.

Can anyone shed any light?

```
Namespace CustomControl
Public Class mycontrol : Inherits Literal
    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        Dim value As String = "test"
        If _doubleit = True Then
            value = value & "&nbsp;test"
        End If

        MyBase.Text = value
        MyBase.CreateChildControls()
    End Sub

    Private Shared _doubleit As Boolean = True
    Public Shared Property doubleit() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _doubleit
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _doubleit = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Shared` from your variable and from your property declaration. `Shared` means exactly that what you *don't* want: *All* instances share the same value.

So, your code should look like this:

```
Private _doubleit As Boolean = True
Public Property doubleit() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _doubleit
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _doubleit = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: It's just that simple... Thanks!